# When I used splash to login, its method, send_text doesn't work, and the post request was cancelled

Tags: python, lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash, splash-js-render

**splash method send_text() doesn't work? **

something wrong in my login simulation with using splash to login a wibsite, the table did not recieve value i post, and i found a red massage in the 'HAR()' data , which denoted the post request was cancelled. why?

Comment: i also find the "302" in the post request

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.